# Don't know how to hide a div with a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

This is my firt question on Stack Overflow.
I want to create a Monopoly game where you have to scan a QR code to take possession of the road after you have bought it.
I have imagined that for each street, you will be taken to a separate page, which will set a cookie. After 3 seconds I will be automatically redirected to my main page, where my streets will be displayed to me. I want to solve this so that there are already all 22 streets on the page. By default all are hidden. The streets that belong to me are then shown when you have the right cookie for it. I have already coded something, but this doesn't work. Could you help me?
I first tried to hide an element when I have the right cookie. Unfortunately this does not work. I know this is the opposite of what I want. It was just faster this way.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js" 
</script>
<script>
if ($.cookie("Karte") === "Schlossallee1") {
 $("p").hide();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Disappear.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the first site, where you get your cookie.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "Karte";
$cookie_value1 = "Schlossallee1";
$cookie_value2 = "Schlossallee2";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", "example.com", 1);
?>
<html>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
  echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=https://example.com/monopoly/Spiel/index.php">
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this for the beginning.

```js
if (getCookie("Karte") === "Schlossallee1") {
  $("p").show();
} else {
  $("p").hide();
}

/* Copied function below from w3schools */
/*https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp */
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```